# Wordpress default gallery markup with custom image sizes

Tags: wordpress, gallery

Several months ago, based on code on Stack and some user's support here I've created custom HTML markup for default WP gallery. It's contains custom image sizes and they are depended of screen width size. Everything worked fine unitl now. I didn't change anything but now those new image sizes aren't show up. Of course those thumbnails sizes was genereated, they works in other part of theme. My code looks like this:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'custom_gallery', 10, 2);
function custom_gallery($output, $attr) {
global $post;

if (isset($attr['orderby'])) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby($attr['orderby']);
    if (!$attr['orderby'])
        unset($attr['orderby']);
}

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
    'id' => $post->ID,
    'itemtag' => 'dl',
    'icontag' => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns' => 3,
    'include' => '',
    'exclude' => ''
), $attr));

$id = intval($id);
if ('RAND' == $order) $orderby = 'none';

if (!empty($include)) {
    $include = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include);
    $_attachments = get_posts(array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby));

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ($_attachments as $key => $val) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
}

if (empty($attachments)) return '';

$output = "<div class=\"gallery-wrapper\">\n";

$output .= "<ul class=\"gallery-elements\">\n";

foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {

    $img = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($id);

    $url = $img['sizes']['full']['url'];
    $caption = $img['caption'];
    $alt = $img['alt'];

    if (!array_key_exists('columns', $attr) || !intval($attr['columns'])) {
      $output .= "<li class=\"gallery-item gallery-item-3\">\n";
      $url1s =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-small']['url'];
      $url1b =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-small-retina']['url'];
      $url2s =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-medium']['url'];
      $url2b =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-medium-retina']['url'];
      $url3s =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-bigger']['url'];
      $url3b =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-bigger-retina']['url'];
      $url4s =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-huge']['url'];
      $url4b =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-huge-retina']['url'];
      $url5s =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-monster']['url'];
      $url5b =  $img['sizes']['gallery-3col-monster-retina']['url'];
      $output .= 
      "<a href=\"$url\" data-fancybox=\"gallery\" title=\"$alt\">
      <picture class=\"lozad\" data-src=\"$url5s 1x, $url5b 2x\" data-alt=\"$alt\" title=\"$alt\">
      <source media=\"(min-width: 1440px)\" srcset=\"$url5s 1x, $url5b 2x\">
      <source media=\"(min-width: 1024px)\" srcset=\"$url4s 1x, $url4b 2x\">
      <source media=\"(min-width: 768px)\" srcset=\"$url3s 1x, $url3b 2x\">
      <source media=\"(min-width: 425px)\" srcset=\"$url2s 1x, $url2b 2x\">
      <source media=\"(min-width: 300px)\" srcset=\"$url1s 1x, $url1b 2x\">
      </picture>
      </a>";

      if ($caption) { 
          $output .= "<div class=\"gallery-caption \">{$caption}</div>\n";
      }
      $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

    else if ($attr['columns'] == 1) {

      // output for 1 row

    } else if ($attr['columns'] == 2) {

      // output for 2 rows

    } else if ($attr['columns'] == 4) {

      // output for 4 rows
    }
}

$output .= "</ul>\n";
$output .= "</div>\n";

return $output;
}

add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
```

This markup works, but images URLs not. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you fix this? Just found a similar problem with wp_prepare_attachment_for_js() not returning custom defined image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` includes custom image sizes by default - you need to include them by means of the `image_size_names_choose` filter.

I had problems with this function recently, when the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin removed a filter override to `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()` - this was making all image sizes available to the `wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()`, and was removed in ACF 5.8.3: https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/commit/66b1383e5614188c20fc5ff8ae04bb9dc0e154f6#diff-e2ae20a151c20a3d2975705c600fae75L378.

Try adding the following to add your additional image sizes:

```
<?php
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', function($atts) {
    // Get an array of custom image sizes
    $allImageSizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();
    $imageSizes = [];

    // Loop through the custom images, make a suitable array
    foreach ($allImageSizes as $key => $value) {
        $imageSizes[$key] = $key;
    }

    // Merge the new array with the existing, and return
    $atts = array_merge($atts, $imageSizes);
    return $atts;
});
```